# How To Calculate Sum of jqgrid columns on footer row Locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jqgrid

After Displaying my database into jqgrid i need to add summary footer row which needs to calculate the sum of the particular column.I am populating Jqgrid locally..Also I have added Jqgrid Filter Which filters the data .According to my need I want my Summary footer to get changed on filtering the data from jqgrid filter toolbar...

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
var gridData = null;
var nn = null;
$.ajax({
    url: 'Default.aspx/MyMethod',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (ReportDataNew, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        gridData = JSON.parse(ReportDataNew.d);
        console.log(gridData);

        $("#gridId").jqGrid({
            data: gridData,
            datatype: "local",
            height: '100%',
            autowidth: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            colNames: ['UserName', 'Ordinal', 'Extension', 'Trunk', 'Dialnumber', 'DialDate', 'DialTime', 'Duration', 'Destination', 'Price'],
            colModel: [
                       { name: 'username', index: 'username', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                       { name: 'ordinal', index: 'ordinal', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                       { name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center'}
                      ]
```

I need to calculate the sum of `price` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you definition of the local data you could include a segment containing the `userdata` information that would be displayed in the footer.  Before your pass the data to the grid you could then calculate the values that would be passed inside these variables.

Ex of the `userdata:`

```
 userdata = new { colOneName = "Totals:", colTwoName = totalsVariableFromLocalCalculation}
```

Then in your grid you would turn on footers via

```
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir for ur response..I added footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true in my code..But where i need to add other line ..Plz sir I updated my question with my code...Plz sir help me in that

Comment: You would need to iterate over your data rows summing the price data.  Then in the example above you would set colTwoName to the this sum.

Answer (score 0):

put the below code in your jqGrid to calculate the sum of price:

```
footerrow:true,
loadComplete : function(){
var $grid = $("your grid id");
var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol','price',false,'sum');
$grid.jqGrid('footerData','set',{price : colSum});
}
```